# zxing Datamatrix generator creating rectangular barcode which can't be scanned

Tags: zxing, datamatrix

I am using barcodewriter to write datamatrix barcoe. While most of the times it creates correct square style datamatrix barcode, for some of text it creates rectangular shaped barcode.

For inputData like below it creates rectangular barcode
8004600000070000017
C/TH PAUL PENGELLY
C/TH NICKY PARSONS
C/TH ROSEMARIE BARTOLOME

while for others it creates square styled: CTH HEKT-WOODROW MORGAN
800460000007
800460000007000001700000

i am usinf this code to generate code:
BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter() { Format = BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX };
 var img = writer.Write(inputData);
return new Bitmap(img);

img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                dto.BarcodeImage = ms.ToArray();

How can I make sure that I always get Square shaped datamatrix?
I have alread tried adding height,width options.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
There is SymbolShape option which can be used to force shape .
 DatamatrixEncodingOptions options = new DatamatrixEncodingOptions()
            {
                Height = 300,
                Width = 300,
                PureBarcode = true,
                Margin = 1,
                SymbolShape = SymbolShapeHint.FORCE_SQUARE
            };
```

Comment: Not available in the C# version.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to detect but after careful reviewing, I found how to do it.

```
readonly DataMatrixWriter DMencoder = new();
readonly Dictionary<EncodeHintType, object> DMencodeType = new() 
{ 
  [EncodeHintType.DATA_MATRIX_DEFAULT_ENCODATION] = Encodation.C40, //Optional
  [EncodeHintType.DATA_MATRIX_SHAPE] = SymbolShapeHint.FORCE_SQUARE
};
DMencoder.encode(matrixText, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX, 100, 100, DMencodeType)
```